# How can I return a reference to a local variable specifying that its lifetime is the same as self?

Tags: arrays, rust, slice, lifetime

I'd like to write some code like below

```
struct SomeData(u8, u8);

impl SomeData {
    fn to_bytes(&self) -> &[u8] {
        let mut bytes: [u8; 16] = [0; 16];

        // fill up buffer with some data in `SomeData`.
        bytes[0] = self.0;
        bytes[1] = self.1;

        // return slice
        &bytes[..]
    }
}
```

I know the reason why above code doesn't work. How can I return a reference specifying that its lifetime is the same as `self`?

Comment: But `buffer` is a local variable here ? What is the link with `self` ? Why don't just move the value ?

Comment: *I know the reason why above code doesn't work* — Would you care to share why you think it *should* work?

Comment: It seems that I didn't understand much about Rust. Thanks all of your answers!

Answer (score 4):

Explicit lifetime annotation of a reference cannot extend lifetime of an object it refers to. `bytes` is a local variable and it will be destroyed when function ends.

One option is to return an array

```
fn to_bytes(&self) -> [u8;16] {
    ...
    // return array
    bytes
}
```

Another one is to pass mutable slice into function

```
fn to_bytes(&self, bytes: &mut [u8]) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you want a function to return a reference:

```
fn to_bytes(&self) -> &[u8]
```

It is possible only if that reference points to its argument (in this case `self`), because it has a longer lifetime than the function. Example (with a slice-friendly `SomeData`):

```
struct SomeData([u8; 16]);

impl SomeData {
    fn to_bytes(&self) -> &[u8] {
        &self.0[8..]
    }
}
```

In your case you are attempting to return a slice of a local variable and since that variable's lifetime ends by the time the `to_bytes` function returns, the compiler refuses to provide a reference to it.

Comment: It's also possible if the reference points to something with the `'static` lifetime.